# Hibernate limit result inquiry

Tags: java, hibernate

How does maxresult property of hibernate query works? in the example below :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from MyTable");
query.setMaxResults(10);
```

Does this get all rows from database, but only 10 of them are displayed? or this is same as `limit` in sql.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's the same as `LIMIT`, but it is database-independent. For example MS SQL Server does not have LIMIT, so hibernate takes care of translating this. For MySQL it appends `LIMIT 10` to the query.

So, always use `query.setMaxResults(..)` and `query.setFirstResult(..)` instead of native sql clauses.

Answer (score 0):

SetMaxResults retrieves all the rows and displays the number of rows that are set. In my case I didn't manage to find a method that can really retrieve only a limit number of rows. 
My recommendation is to create the query yourself and set there "rownum" or "limit".